# How can I unblock pop-up in any browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

**Help needed.**

I have done a lot of R&D to come up with the solution on **unblocking the pop-up on the browser** but not been able to resolve this issue so I would like to know your valuable thoughts/solutions.

**My requirement;**
1. When user fills the form and get the successful message, then the new window appears in the same browser with external link.

I have tried the below tricks to solve this.

1. I have write the below code for new window.

   ```
   window.open("/","NewWindow",'width=100,height=100');
   ```

OR

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.open("/","NewWindow",'width=100,height=100');
},1000);
```

OR

```
open("/","NewWindow",'scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=100,height=100,left=-1000,top=-1000');
```

2. Also I'm created an anchor and trigger click event, but pop-up is still getting blocked.

Please help.

Comment: See async window.open() example here https://gist.github.com/jayphelps/dc8556e72caaf8b2ac5596afcf91498d

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible. If a popup is blocked on the user's end, it's blocked. You cannot programmaticly unblock it.

However, you got alternatives:

- You can use [modals](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp): Although it looks like one, a modal is not a popup, and it won't be blocked.
- You can also ask the user to unblock your site from the popup blockers (show them a warning). Many sites do this.